# Shell Script piping

Tags: shell, plsql

```
#!/bin/sh
output=ANIL;

#
# Ask user for database inputs
#

    echo -n "Enter Database Server Hostname: " 
    read dba_host
    echo -n "Enter Database SID: " 
    read dba_sid
    echo -n "Enter DBA User: " 
    read dba_usr
    echo -n "Enter DBA password: " 
    read dba_pwd
    echo -n "What daemon are we using: "
    read daemon_str

#
#  Loop to connect to database and exit if something is found
#
while :
do

    output=`sqlplus $dba_usr/$dba_pwd@$dba_sid <<+ | grep '^-' | sed 's/-//'
    set serveroutput on
    DECLARE

    command         VARCHAR2(50);
    return_name         VARCHAR2(30);
    value           VARCHAR2(10000);
    status          INT;
    system_time         TIMESTAMP := SYSTIMESTAMP;

    WHILE TRUE
    BEGIN

        status := DBMS_PIPE.RECEIVE_MESSAGE($daemon_str);
        IF status = 0 THEN
            DMS_PIPE.UNPACK_MESSAGE(command);

        END IF;

        IF command = "STOP" THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STOP was encountered') >> file.log;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(system_time) >> file.log;
            BREAK

        ELSIF command = "SYSTEM" THEN
            DBMS_PIPE.UNPACK_MESSAGE(return_name);
            DBMS_PIPE.UNPACK_MESSAGE(value);
            EXIT
            $value

        ELSIF command = "SQL"
            DBMS_PIPE.UNPACK_MESSAGE(return_name);
            DBMS_PIPE.UNPACK_MESSAGE(value);
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE value;
        ELSE
            nap(10)
        EXCEPTION
           WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_ouput.put_line('Unknown Input Error') >> file.log;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(system_time) >> file.log;

    DBMS_PIPE.PACK_MESSAGE('done');
    DBMS_PIPE.PACK_MESSAGE(status);
    status := DBMS_PIPE.SEND_MESSAGE(return_name,10);

    END;

    dbms_output.put_line(chr(10) || '-' || command);

    END;
    /
    exit

+`
echo $output

done
```

I am trying to convert a c code block to what you see now a shell script block. I am just a beginner in this coding language and was wanting to know if anyone is seeing something I am not. To sum up what I am trying to accomplish is ask user for the oracle database they want to connect to then keep connection and receive things through pipe. Then the usual of unpacking, outputting errors and such. Then sending it back through same pipe. Any input on possible syntax or anything at all that could be causing this to constantly echo out nothing but blank lines from while loop.

Comment: Rather than prompting the user for parameters, take them as command line arguments.

Comment: There is never a need to run a command store its output and then echo that output.  Just let the command print its output directly.